# Accessing a docker web app running on Ubuntu AWS via the internet (http://... 80)

Tags: docker

I am very new to docker. I have inherited some code which was running in a unknown configuration to publish a website (with a MYSQL backend). I am trying to install and run this on AWS ubuntu linux server.

I have managed to successfuly finish docker compose with the following result:

[docker compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t2As.png)

```bash
docker ps
```

is successful
[docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m20kQ.png)

This is supposed to run a website that I want to access via the internet. I have opened up port 80 in the security group of the EC2.

However when I visit the page http://...:80 i don't see anything.

I suspect this is something very simple that I am missing. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please, do not post images when you could just copy/paste the text (surround 'code' or output with triple backticks ```).

Comment: We will probably need to see the compose file

Answer (score 0):

It could be a lot of different issues, but a simple thing that a lot of people miss, is opening the port for the container by adding this line to your service in the docker-compose.yml file

```
ports:
  - "80:80"
```

to open port 80 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you create or run a container using docker create or docker run, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world.

You can use -p 8080:80 to map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the ec2 host.